# compiler converts type character to integer randomly

Tags: c, char, integer, stack

> I'm trying to create a **stack** with *two* functions. **push** (which inserts data at the top of the stack) and **pop** (which removes data from top of the stack). But at the last line when I want to print the pop item, it gives me the following error!

[The Error Message in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1W1S.jpg)

> It says "format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’.
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)."

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 20

void push(char stack[], int *top, char new){
    if(*top < STACK_SIZE){
    (*top)++;
    stack[*top] = new;
}
    else
        printf("Stack is full!");
}

char pop(char stack[], int *top){
    char item;
    if(*top >= 0){
        item = stack[*top];
        (*top)--;
    }else{
        printf("stack is empty");
        item = ' ';
    }
    return item;
}

int main(){
    char s[STACK_SIZE];
    int s_top = -1;
    push(s, &s_top, 'C');
    push(s, &s_top, 'A');
    push(s, &s_top, 'H');

    char item = pop(s, &s_top);
    printf("%s", item); // The Error Line?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As the compiler says, `%s` is for strings using a pointer to the first character, i.e. `char *`. But `item` is a variable of type `char`. It's a *single* character, not a string. For which you need to use the `%c` format.

Comment: @Some programmer dude. Wow I didn't know that! Thanks a lot.

Comment: For future questions: Your error message is plain text output. Please copy&paste any text input/output or code directly into the question (use formatted text) instead of showing pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%s", item); // The Error Line?
// Change this %s --> %c
```